# _Router2.default.computeRootMatch is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-router

this is my code.

```
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
   const branch = matchRoutes(routes, req.url);
   ...
});
```

Comment: If you share some of your code it would be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a few days ago and found that downgrading `react-router-config` to `1.0.0-beta.X` fixed this problem. While I know this isn't a technical or permanent solution it helps if you need functionality now.

[source - github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6381#issuecomment-428858013)